# How to remove commas on discord.js replies with map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I was doing this shop command for my discord server, and it's suppose to show the shop items list one by one, but it's not what's happening, I don't want it to reply the shop list with commas between the items, and I don't know how to remove them, here is the code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require("discord.js");
const items = require("../shopitem")
const client = require("..");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
     .setName("shop")
     .setDescription("See the avaliable items to buy!"),
    async execute(interaction) {

        if (items.lenght === 0) {
        return await interaction.reply("There is no items here!", { ephemeral: true });
        }

        const shopList = items
        .map((value) => {
            return (` ${value.price} - ${value.item}\n`);
        });

        let embed_shop = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("**|** ***Store:***")
        .setDescription(`${shopList}`)
        .setThumbnail(interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp(Date.now())
        .setAuthor({
            name: interaction.user.username,
            iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
             url: null
        })
        .setFooter({
        iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
        url: null,
        text: `Sistema exclusivo ${client.user.username}®`
        })
        .setColor("#FF0090");
        
        await interaction.reply({ embeds : [embed_shop] });
    },
    
};
```

when i use the command it replies the embed correctly but the shop list stay like this:

100 - Backpack
, 500 - Radio
, 1000 - Smartphone

and i wanted it to be like this, withou commas:

100 - Backpack
 500 - Radio
 1000 - Smartphone

i expect to find a simple way to remove these commas since i've never used .map, and it's my first time doing this, i have no idea of how the function works, just the basic

Answer (score 1):

In JS, when a array is converted to a string directly, it will join each item in the array with a comma (`,`). You can change this behavior by calling `shopList.join("")`.  That will insert an empty string between each item in the array and return a single string.

You can also join using other strings to join as well, such as a newline (`\n`), like this: `shopList.join("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
.setDescription(`${shopList.join(" ")}`)
```

let me know if that's not it